# git switch which repository is active

Tags: git, repository, cd

**Question:**

If I am working on two separate projects (repositories stored locally)

```
~/Documents/git-repositories/fooproject
~/Documents/git-repositories/barproject
```

and I am pushing to a remote server, how do I switch repositories?

**Details:**

I am working on my `fooproject`. I `cd` into the `fooproject` directory locally, make changes, git add, commit, and push. The changes all end up in the correct remote repository, `fooproject`.

But what if I want to work on `barproject` now, a totally different repository? Can I just `cd` into the `barproject` directory, make changes, git add, commit, and push? Will everything end up in `barproject` remotely? Or will it end up in `fooproject`, because I haven't made any sort of changes to some `git` setting?

Does the answer lie in the `.git` file that would change when I `cd` into a different repo?

**Research and Background:**

I think that the way to switch the active repository has something to do with `git remote add origin`? I don't know for sure, and I don't want to wreck my repositories by doing something uninformed/foolish. Which is why I came to you guys first!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repositories in Git are self-contained; the `.git` subdirectory in each project contains all the project-specific information such as the default push destination (which is the remote named `origin`).

So the answer is: Under normal circumstances changing directories will change where the default push destination goes.

You can check this by using the command:

```
git remote -v
```

in each repository to see where `origin` points to.

Comment: Sweet! I thought it had something to do with that. Thanks a bunch :)